# how to use ImageProcessor Class library

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey guys May I know how to use image processor class library Please, I logged into the  provider website "https://imageprocessor.org/" but there is nothing wroten about using it thanks a lot for your time guys and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their website, there is a documentation about ImageFactory class which has a demo code for every method and showing the result.
You can find it here:[ImageFactory](https://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/)

Here is a complete example *taken from their documentation* to load an image and do some operations to it and save it:

```
byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
// Format is automatically detected though can be changed.
ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat { Quality = 70 };
Size size = new Size(150, 0)
using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
{
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Initialize the ImageFactory using the overload to preserve EXIF metadata.
        using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData:true))
        {
            // Load, resize, set the format and quality and save an image.
            imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                        .Resize(size)
                        .Format(format)
                        .Save(outStream);
        }
        // Do something with the stream.
    }
}
```

Here is an example from their documentation:
Change backgroundColor:

```
public ImageFactory BackgroundColor(Color color)
```

Crop image:

```
public ImageFactory Crop(Rectangle rectangle)
```

Change the resoluation:

```
public ImageFactory Resolution(300, 300)
```

Add a watermark to image:

```
public ImageFactory Watermark (TextLayer textLayer)
```

And many many more. Just navigate to the url and you'll find all of them.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your help and thanks a lot for your time